# Monitor RSS/Atom feed

Tags: python, web-scraping, rss, rss-reader

I want to figure out constantly monitor an RSS feed (Python 2.7, using feedparser) or any other library.

Means if blog add a new article we get alert.
and if article in db != new article then add this article in our db.

I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Always smart to start with the documentation of the module you intend to use. In the case of Feedparser that would be in the link below:

https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/index.html

Follow the instructions, tinker the code, make a few mistakes, learn from them, get familiar with the module. It's the only way you can learn.

Comment: yes, "follow ... tinker ... learn ... get familiar ..." AND then post a Q to stackoverflow with your best attempt to solve the problem. Good luck.